# Why html:5 can't expand with `sudo vim /var/www/html/test.ph'?

Tags: vim, emmet

Here is my vim configuration.

```
cat .vimrc
filetype plugin indent on
let g:user_emmet_install_global = 0
autocmd FileType html,css,php EmmetInstall
```

`html:5` can be expanded into whole proper format when to edit with `vim test.php`.
Why `html:5` can not be expanded into whole proper format when to edit with `sudo vim /var/www/html/test.ph`?

Comment: `sudo vim` runs `vim` under different user (`root`) so `vim` perhaps has a different configuration. Try `sudo -H vim` (`sudo` runs `vim` but preserves `$HOME` so `vim` uses your config instead of root). Please be warned that `sudo -H` can change ownership of your files to root so get ready to run `sudo chown -R scrapy ~scrapy`.

Comment: Did you try `sudoedit` ?